# Elipses not getting added to the material UI tabs text

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to the web development. Here , I am trying to add the ellipsis for the span element which is label in the tabs.

```
<div class="MuiTabs-scroller MuiTabs-fixed" role="tablist" style="overflow: hidden;">
   <div class="MuiTabs-flexContainer">
     <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTab-root VIP_tabRoot MuiTab-textColorInherit Mui-selected VIP_tabSelected" tabindex="0" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="true">
       <span class="MuiTab-wrapper VIP_tabIconWrapper">Test004</span>
    </button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Now, Here I am trying to add the text-overflow for this span text. I have applied the following solution,

```
.VIP_tabIconWrapper { 
   max-width : 100px;
   text-overflow: elipses;
   word-wrap: no-wrap;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

But still I am not able to add that. Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score -1):

Here is how this can be achieved:

```css
.VIP_tabIconWrapper { 
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

- The element needs to be `inline-block`
- you must provide a `width` property
- and you had a typo on ellipsis :)